# SQL Server: JOIN multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables.

This table is used to store customer's infos

`Customers`:

```
ID          Name
1           'Company A'
2           'Company B'
3           'Company C'
```

This table save the order log

`Orders`:

```
ID          CustomerID         Quantity      Date
1           1                  200           01/01/2001
2           1                  150           01/02/2001
3           2                  500           01/02/2001
4           3                  200           01/03/2001
5           2                  400           01/03/2001
6           3                  200           01/04/2001
```

This table to save the price, let's assume that I sell only 1 product, and each Customer have a separate price for their own and the total quantity like this

example: for customer ID 1, the total quantity between FROM 0 TO 100 THEN the PRICE for each one is 200

`Price`:

```
CustomerID           From           To          Price
1                    0              100         200
1                    101            500         190
1                    501            ?           180
2                    0              150         195
2                    151            800         180
2                    801            ?           170
3                    0              400         180
3                    401            ?           180
```

I want my output look like this:

```
Name          TotalQuantity            Price
---------------------------------------------
Company A     350                      190
Company B     900                      170
Company C     400                      180
```

I know that I need to `SUM` the `Quantity` first then compare with `Price` table below but how can I do that? And what should I put in "?" erm... for example more than 501, 801, 401  in that `Price` table?

Comment: It's in StackOverflow spirit to show us what queries you have tried before posting your problem, so that we can see you put some effort in this yourself, apart from asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things per customer you are interested in: the sum of orders and the according price. So let's join these with the customer table:

```
select c.id, c.name, p.price
from customers c
join
(
  select customerid, sum(quantity) as total
  from orders
  group by customerid
) o on o.customerid = c.id
join price p on p.customerid = o.customerid and o.total between p.from and p.to;
```

As to no upper bound: Store some super-great value and you are done. Or store null and use and `o.total between p.from and coalesce(p.to,o.total)` instead.